# You Only Look Once (YOLO): Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

This question refers to the [YOLO architecture](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/yolo_1.pdf) (figure 3).

In their architecture they define a convolutional layer `7x7x64-s-2` followed by a maxpool layer `2x2-s-2`.  These transform an input of `448x448x3` into a tensor of `112x112x192`, using a kernel of `7x7` in the convolutional layer.

Can someone please clarify this notation `7x7x64-s-2`?

I'm assuming `s-2` refers to stride of 2. Then is 64 the padding?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel has a size of **7x7**.  There are **64** convolution filters in the first layer.  The stride is **2**.  In the image below you can see the input and output of each layer.  When you run YOLO you will see this in the command prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The other answers up now look good, but I thought it might help with clarity if I went through each shape transformation.

**Input**: image with height `448`, width `448`, and `3` color channels (e.g. RGB, BGR, HSV)

```
448 x 448 x 3
```

**Apply convolution kernel** `7x7x64-s-2`.

```
224 x 224 x 192
```

The first two dimensions are halved, due to the stride of `2`. The final dimension is `192` because, presumably, the kernel is applied to each `448 x 448 x 1` layer of the image individually, then the outputs of all 3 are stacked (note: `192 = 3 * 64`).

**Apply maxpool** `2x2-s-2`

```
112 x 112 x 192
```

Pooling a `2 x 2` area with stride `2` essentially means that you pool over separate blocks of the input tensor. The stride `2` is why the first two dimensions are halved. This is applied separately to each of `192` layers, so the final dimension remains the same.

Comment: thanks, make sense. But what happen in the next layer, why input 112*112*192, a conv layer 3*3*192, a maxpooling layer 2*2-s-2, output 56*56*256? how did this 256 comes?

Comment: My guess is that there are 256 individual `3 x 3 x 192` filters used. If you convolve one `3 x 3 x 192` filter over the first two axis of a `112 x 112 x 192` input, you get `112 x 112 x 1` output. 
So, you'd learn 256 unique conv filters (each of shape `3 x 3 x 192`, outputting `112 x 112 x 1`), and stack their outputs (`112 x 112 x 256`).

Comment: I run the code to check what happen, in face, the Figure 3 in the paper kind of misleading. first 7*7*64-s-2 conv and the next 2*2-s-2 max pooling layer would output a 112*112*64. and the next 3*3*192 conv would output 112*112*192. the operation on channel is stacking. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The first two numbers are the size of the filter/kernel, that much is certain.  I think the third number is either the depth of the filter or the number of filters.  For the first layer, it could be the depth of the filter, giving us 64 for each of the three --192, which is the depth of the output.  However this same line of reasoning appears not to hold for the next layer.